# Dishwasher Dripping Water From Both Sides Directly Below The Door Gasket

Tags: dishwasher

My dishwasher is dripping water, from what appears to the black "plastic" that lines the inside "drum" of the washer.  When the dishwasher is running, I see a steady steady slow drip coming from the black plastic? lining that goes around the inside on the front right side (when facing).  This isn't the best image, but it should illustrate where the drip is coming from.  The drip comes from the bottom of the black plastic directly below the insulation.

(from googling this piece may be called the dishwasher door gasket??)

What replacement piece do I need to stop this drip?  Or what do I need to do to stop the drip?
[image: Drip Image]

**EDIT**
After letting the dishwasher run a full cycle while empty, I noticed that it is actually leaking from the same location on both sides.

Also, per comments below, I followed [Check Dishwasher Float Valve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPtfU1s1kEo) and I heard clicking when pulling it up from inside the dishwasher, as well as pressing the "button" from up under the dishwasher

Comment: That's a good detail pic. Maybe back up a bit and give an overview shot of where this is to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that rubber piece is meant as a water seal.

Sounds like the dishwasher door seal (which is not the piece shown in the photo) is damaged, or maybe the water level in the dishwasher when it's running is too high.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect the water level.

Comment: Can you find and look at the float?  It should be in the bottom of the washer tub, maybe enclosed in a plastic screen.  You can also sometimes see it from underneath the dishwasher.

Comment: @SteveSh - what would it look like?  Can I see it when I have the dishwasher door open?

Comment: @user2676140 - Not sure you can see it with the door open.  If you take the bottom panel of the dishwasher off and use a flashlight, you may be able to discern it from underneath.  It may be no more than a rod that moves up & down a couple of inches depending on the water level in the tub.  That rod then opens or closes a switch and the fill valve which stops the fill cycle and starts the wash cycle.

Comment: @SteveSh - I watched this YouTube video on checking the float, and when I manually lifted it up from the top I heard a click, and when I pressed the "button" on the bottom I also heard a click.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPtfU1s1kEo (also, I just edited my OP, I let the dishwasher run a full cycle and it's leaking on both the left and right side same location)